# How do I map a 3D triangle into 2D?

Tags: 3d, triangles, coordinate-systems

The problem I'm having is mapping a 3D triangle into 2 dimensions. I have three points in $(x,y,z)$ form, and want to map them onto the plane described by the normal of the triangle, such that I end up with three points in $(x,y)$ form.

My guess would be it'd assign an arbitrary up vector and then doing something? Finding the distance traveled along the plane from one vertex to another? What do I do, and how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified the problem well enough.  Do you have three points $(x_1,y_1,z_1), (x_2,y_2,z_2), (x_3,y_3,z_3)$ to map to two dimensional points?  The simplest is to ignore the third coordinate.  This is not as stupid as it sounds-you are projecting the triangle on the $xy$ plane.  If you want to project onto another plane, how is it defined?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it a little more clear. I don't know if it's clear enough to explain what I want done, because honestly my understanding of the math involved is at such a rudimentary level I might not be able to properly formulate the question. Sorry. Is it clearer now? I want to basically imagine the plane the triangle lies in as being the new XY plane, and map into that.

Comment: If your vector is normal (perpendicular) to the plane  you want to project onto, the operation is well-defined.  You can rotate so that the vector is along $z$, ignore the last coordinate, then rotate back.  You will have three points, each with three coordinates, that lie in a plane perpendicular to the vector you have chosen.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My take on this is that you want to find a mapping of the form
$(x, y, z) \mapsto (ax+by+cz, dx+ey+fz) $
so the resulting triangle in the plane is the same shape and size as the original triangle.
Let $L_{ij}$ be the distance between points $i$ and $j$.
Since we have 6 unknowns, we need 6 equations.

Let’s map $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ into $(0, 0)$. We get
$ax_1+by_1+cz_1 = 0$ and $dx_1+ey_1+fz_1 = 0$.
Let’s map $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ into $(L_{12}, 0)$. We get
$ax_2+by_2+cz_2 = L_{12}$ and $dx_2+ey_2+fz_2 = 0$.

Compute the point $(u, v)$ which is $L_{13}$ from $(0, 0)$ and $L_{23}$ from $(L_{12}, 0)$. The sine and cosine laws are your friends here.
Map $(x_3, y_3, z_3)$ into $(u, v)$ via
$ax_3+bx_3+cz_3 = u$ and $dx_3+ey_3+fz_3 = v$.

Solve these two sets of $3\times 3$ equations, and there’s your mapping.

Comment: Wow - you are right.

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about the shape of the triangle, not about its orientation, then it is reasonably simple -just calculate the distances between the points. I believe that is what Ralph Dratman is doing above.

Let us have the three 3D points

```
x1, y1, z1
x2, y2, z2
x3, y3, z3
```

Let us call the sides of the triangle a, b and c, and its vertices A, B, C.

```
a = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2)
b = sqrt((x3-x2)^2 + (y3-y2)^2 + (z3-z2)^2)
c = sqrt((x1-x3)^2 + (y1-y3)^2 + (z1-z3)^2)
```

To draw this triangle, you can choose any orientation and position. One choice is

```
A: [0,0] 
B: [a,0]
```

The position of C would now need to be calculated using the above calculated sides a, b, c.

```
C: [xc, yc]
```

According to Wolfram Alpha (after label adjustment):

```
yc = sqrt((a + b - c) (a - b + c) (-a + b + c) (a + b + c))/(2 a)
xc = sqrt(c^2 - yc^2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have three points A(x_1, y_1, z_1) , B(x_2, y_2, z_2), C(x_3, y_3, z_3).  You can have the axes of the coordinate system attached to the plane containing $A,B,C$ anywhere on this plane, and the orientation of the its $x', y'$ axes can be oriented freely as well.  So to specify the problem further, let's assume that you want to place point $A$ at the origin of the $O'x'y'$ plane (which is coincident with the plane of the triangle).  Further, assume that the $x'$ axis is chosen to be along the vector $\vec{AB}$.  These two assumptions make the coordinate system $O'x'y'$ unique.  It is specified in steps as follows:

Step 1:  Find the normal vector to the plane of the triangle, this is given by

$ N = ( B - A) \times (C - A ) $

Step 2:  Normalize vector $N$ by defining the unit vector along its direction by

$\hat{n} = \dfrac{N}{\| N \| } $

Step 3:  Choose the $x'$ axis to point in the direction of $\vec{AB} = B - A $, therefore, the unit vector along the $x'$ axis will be

$ \hat{x'}= \dfrac{ B - A}{\| B - A \|} $

Step 4:  Now for the right handed system, the $y'$ axis unit vector is given by

$ \hat{y'} = \hat{n} \times \hat{x'} $

Step 5:  Place the three vectors $\hat{x'}, \hat{y'}, \hat{n} $ are the columns of a $3 \times 3 $ matrix R $ in this order.

Step 6:  The coordinate system $O' x' y' n$ and the world coordinate system are related by

$ \large {P = A + R Q} $

where $P = [x, y, z]^T $ is the coordinate vector of a point expressed in the world coordinate frame, and $Q$ is the coordinate vector of the same point expressed in the frame what we just constructed.

From Step 6.  we have

$Q = R^T (P - A) $

So for our triangle, we have

$A' = R^T (A - A) = 0 $

$B' = R^T (B - A) $

$C' = R^T (C - A) $

Points $A', B', C'$ are the coordinate vectors in the coordinate system $Ox'y'z'$ (the $z'$ axis is the axis along $\hat{n}$ ).  Note that the $z'$ coordinate of $A', B', C'$ is zero, therefore, we effectively transformed the $3D$ world coordinates of $A,B,C$ to $2D$ coordinates in the reference frame $O'x'y'z'$ that we constructed in steps 1. through 6.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the three vertices of the 3D triangle are given by three coordinate triples $a, b, c$. For example, $b = \{x_b,y_b,z_b\}$. In Mathematica 10, a 2D triangle congruent to this 3D triangle is

```
SSSTriangle[Norm[b-a], Norm[c-b], Norm[a-c]]
```

I do not see an obvious way to use the original 3D coordinates to position the new triangle in 2D space. SSSTriangle uses an arbitrary but consistent placement.